# Resize frontend edit window joomla 2.5

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to increase the width size of my frontend editing window.
I have seen in the Joomla forum that it is a column issue (I did not really understood what was said on it...) on guy said that I should change `task  " $_REQUEST[task] " into "layout"` but I do not have that code in my `index.php` of the ("mega") template...
Should I add this line somewhere in the index ? How ? Thanks a lot!

Giom

Ps: I use simpleCE as editor (Working with a phone)

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more than "my frontend editing window" to work from if you want any real attention to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It was a template issue, a div width That wasn't in 100%